# How do I update State inside of a while loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, rerender

Say I have this code.

```js
var s = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
const[arr,setArr]=useState(s);
while(arr.length != 0){
    setArr(arr.splice(0,1));
    console.log(arr); //This returns [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0] and [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0] and so on until []
}
```

I return {arr.length} at the end of the functionanl component. However, it first renders 10, and waits till the whole while loop is run and then renders 1. All the numbers inbettween are simply skipped.

I kind of understand why this happens, but is there anyway I can show all the lengths? I have a sleep function that takes milliseconds and halts the program for that time, if it is of any use in order to make sure the user can see the rendered lengths for a reasonable time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `const[arr,setArr]=setState(s);` looks very strange. Did you mean `useState` rather than `setState`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a functional component (I'm guessing you meant `useState`, not `setState`, in `const[arr,setArr]=setState(s);`), you need to let the component render each state before setting the next. Otherwise, all the state updates get batched together and the component only renders again when they're all done.

For instance:

```
function Example() {
    const [arr, setArr] = useState([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]);
    // Set up a timer on mount, remove it on dismount and when
    // we run out of values to show
    useEffect(() => {
        const handle = setInterval(() => {
            // Note useing the callback function, so `arr` isn't stale
            // in this callback
            setArr(a => {
                if (a.length) {
                    // Update the array, dropping the first entry
                    return a.slice(1);
                }
                // No more entries, stop the timer
                clearInterval(handle);
                return a;
            });
        }, 500);
        return () => clearInterval(handle);
    }, []);
    return <div>{arr.join()}</div>;
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! I never quite understood setInterval but it certainly comes in use! You also actually answered another question of mine in the same answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65123840/how-do-i-cycle-through-the-elements-of-an-array-inside-of-a-div-tag-one-by-one-i.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `useEffect` hook

Each time, we change `arr`, hook will be called with some timeout

```
const SHOW_TIMEOUT = 300;
var s = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];

const [arr, setArr] = useState(s);

useEffect(() => {
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => setArr(arr.slice(1)), SHOW_TIMEOUT);

  return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId); // also need to stop timeout in case of unmount
}, [arr]);
```

Comment: Sorry. Doesn't work. I think the problem is useEffect is not forcing the update while a while loop is running and the arr is changing

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't like using `useInterval` for any kind of async timing hacking. It creates another variable that you then need to call `clearInterval` on, it's just wonky IMO.

`setTimeout` should also never be a solution for async issues in the browser IMO. It's very error prone, because the internet is variable. If your async function simply takes a little longer than you expect, your functionality breaks.

I solved this same situation using recursive functions. Apparently, this works in useEffect, useEffect won't batch and will update some `useState` hook once the condition is met. You can use a simple count variable to short circuit so you don't end up with an infinite loop.

```
useEffect(() => {
   let count = 0
   function recurseHandleOp() {
      count += 1
      if (count < 100) {
         if (someCondition) {
            setState(true)
         } else {
            recurseHandleOp()
         }
      }
   }
   recurseHandleOp()
}, [])
```